# Explanation of how this MIDI lib for Android works

Tags: android, midi

I'm using the library of @LeffelMania : https://github.com/LeffelMania/android-midi-lib

I'm musician but I've always recorded as studio recordings, not MIDI, so I don't understand some things.

The thing I want to understand is this piece of code:

```
// 2. Add events to the tracks
// Track 0 is the tempo map
TimeSignature ts = new TimeSignature();
ts.setTimeSignature(4, 4, TimeSignature.DEFAULT_METER, TimeSignature.DEFAULT_DIVISION);

Tempo tempo = new Tempo();
tempo.setBpm(228);

tempoTrack.insertEvent(ts);
tempoTrack.insertEvent(tempo);

// Track 1 will have some notes in it
final int NOTE_COUNT = 80;

for(int i = 0; i < NOTE_COUNT; i++)
{
    int channel = 0;
    int pitch = 1 + i;
    int velocity = 100;
    long tick = i * 480;
    long duration = 120;

    noteTrack.insertNote(channel, pitch, velocity, tick, duration);
}
```

Ok, I have 228 Beats per minute, and I know that I have to insert the note after the previous note. What I don't understand is the duration.. is it in milliseconds? it doesn't have sense if I keep the duration = 120 and I set my BPM to 60 for example. Neither I understand the *velocity*

**MY SCOPE**

**I want to insert notes of X pitch with Y duration.**

Could anyone give me some clue?

Comment: `I'm musician but ... not MIDI` - It seems a nonsense, to me, nowadays. Even Kraftwerk, who play for 45+ years are using MIDI (and when they started in 1967 it was all ANALOG ...). Learn something about MIDI [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIDI), "musician"!

Comment: I learnt music for 5 years and I continued my career on my own, I couldn't study music as professional musician. I'm mathematician, Android developer and I play 7 instruments. I've never had the chance to do anything with MIDI because I didn't need it.
Think of people don't "touch" all the fields possible.

Comment: Well, a musician saying "I don't know anything about MIDI" sounds like a programmer who says "I don't know anything about RDBMS" to me.

Comment: you suppose to know everything if you have a role. It's not like this

Comment: No, I don't. I know much less than I would like to. And everyday I learn something. It's still OK to play music "analogically" (i.e.: a guitar, a drum and a trumpet), but a modern musician is supposed AT LEAST to know what MIDI is about, you can't live in the middleage forever. In my opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way MIDI files are designed, notes are in terms of musical length, not time. So when you insert a note, its duration is a number of ticks, not a number of seconds. By default, there are 480 ticks per quarter note. So that code snippet is inserting 80 sixteenth notes since there are four sixteenths per quarter and 480 / 4 = 120. If you change the tempo, they will still be sixteenth notes, just played at a different speed.

If you think of playing a key on a piano, the velocity parameter is the speed at which the key is struck. The valid values are 1 to 127. A velocity of 0 means to stop playing the note. Typically a higher velocity means a louder note, but really it can control any parameter the MIDI instrument allows it to control.

A note in a MIDI file consists of two events: a Note On and a Note Off. If you look at the `insertNote` code you'll see that it is inserting two events into the track. The first is a Note On command at time `tick` with the specified velocity. The second is a Note On command at time `tick + duration` with a velocity of 0.

Pitch values also run from 0 to 127. If you do a Google search for "MIDI pitch numbers" you'll get dozens of hits showing you how pitch number relates to note and frequency.

There is a nice description of timing in MIDI files [here](http://sites.uci.edu/camp2014/2014/05/19/timing-in-midi-files/). Here's an excerpt in case the link dies:

> In a standard MIDI file, there’s information in the file header about “ticks per quarter note”, a.k.a. “parts per quarter” (or “PPQ”). For the purpose of this discussion, we’ll consider “beat” and “quarter note” to be synonymous, so you can think of a “tick” as a fraction of a beat. The PPQ is stated in the last word of information (the last two bytes) of the header chunk that appears at the beginning of the file. The PPQ could be a low number such as 24 or 96, which is often sufficient resolution for simple music, or it could be a larger number such as 480 for higher resolution, or even something like 500 or 1000 if one prefers to refer to time in milliseconds.
>
> What the PPQ means in terms of absolute time depends on the designated tempo. By default, the time signature is 4/4 and the tempo is 120 beats per minute. That can be changed, however, by a “meta event” that specifies a different tempo. (You can read about the Set Tempo meta event message in the file format description document.) The tempo is expressed as a 24-bit number that designates microseconds per quarter-note. That’s kind of upside-down from the way we normally express tempo, but it has some advantages. So, for example, a tempo of 100 bpm would be 600000 microseconds per quarter note, so the MIDI meta event for expressing that would be FF 51 03 09 27 C0 (the last three bytes are the Hex for 600000). The meta event would be preceded by a delta time, just like any other MIDI message in the file, so a change of tempo can occur anywhere in the music.
>
> Delta times are always expressed as a variable-length quantity, the format of which is explained in the document. For example, if the PPQ is 480 (standard in most MIDI sequencing software), a delta time of a dotted quarter note (720 ticks) would be expressed by the two bytes 82 D0 (hexadecimal).

Comment: That's simply what I needed to know. Thanks